# Analytic function on bounded domain with non-negative imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open bounded subset such that $D \cap \mathbb{R} = ]a, b[$ with $b>a.$ Is there **analytic** function $f: D\to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying:

$${\rm Im}(f) \geq 0, \text{and}\,\, f(x) = x\,\, \text{on}\,\, ]a, b[.$$

If $D$ is the whole complex plane, such function doesn't exist, since if not the function $z\mapsto \exp({\rm i}f(z))$ is a bounded analytic function on $\mathbb{C}.$ Thus in view of Liouville theorem, it is constant which implies that $f$ is constant.

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $[a,b]$ has limit points the only analytic function such that $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ is the identity function $f(z)=z$.

PS We cannot have $Im z \geq 0$ for all $z \in \Omega$.